# Error Semantico en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Sucede que para hacer mi programa mas seguro, pido una contraseña al inicio del programa, y esta contraseña es también personalizable (usando la librería ConfigParser), para hacerlo aun mas seguro, el archivo config.ini esta cifrado usando la libreria Pydes, a partir de esto, se utiliza el método entrar, que lo primero que hace es obtener la contraseña que introdujo el usuario, lo segundo es desencriptar el archivo config.ini para poder leerlo, se obtiene el apartado contraseña, y luego se compara lo que introdujo el usuario con lo que esta en el apartado contraseña de config.ini, si la contraseña es incorrecta se muestra un mensaje, si es correcta, se accede al programa, sin embargo al testearlo sucede que,  a pesar de que escriba la contraseña correctamente, me sigue tirando que la contraseña es incorrecta

```
    #Python 3.5
#Office Database v2.0
#Etapa: Desarrollo
#Desarrollador: Cesar Eduardo Cuevas Garza

from tkinter import *
from pyDes import des
from tkinter import messagebox
import configparser
import time
#from dependencies import delete as d
global contraseña_encriptado



def encriptar(contraseña, fichero):
    f = open(fichero, "rb+")
    d = f.read()
    f.close()
    k = des(contraseña)
    d = k.encrypt(d, " ")
    f = open(fichero, "wb+")
    f.write(d)
    f.close()
    return True

def desencriptar(contraseña, fichero):
    f = open(fichero, "rb+")
    d = f.read()
    f.close()
    k = des(contraseña)
    d = k.decrypt(d, " ")
    f = open(fichero, "wb+")
    f.write(d)
    f.close()
    return True

try:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    config.get("Software", "contraseña")
    encriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")
except:
    desencriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")
    encriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")

def main():
    ventana_main = Tk()
    ventana.destroy()
    ventana_main.geometry("800x800+400+100")
    opcion = StringVar(ventana_main)
    bienvenido_label = Label(ventana_main, text = "Bienvenido, Selecciona Una Opcion:", font = ("Helvetica", 24)).place(x = 150, y = 40)
    opciones_spinbox = Spinbox(ventana_main, values = ("Añadir un usuario", "Hola"), textvariable = opcion, width = 60, font = ("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), state = "readonly").place(x = 150, y = 120)

def entrar(x):
    desencriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    final_pass = config.get("Software", "contraseña")
    if str(x) == str(final_pass):
        encriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")
        main()
    else:
        encriptar("#19UmPV@", "config.ini")
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Contraseña Incorrecta")

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Bienvenido")
ventana.geometry("300x300+600+250")
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)
fondo = "#2F4F4F"
letras = "#FFF"
ventana.configure(background = fondo)


try:
    archivo = open("datos.csv")
    config = open("config.ini")
except:
    messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Falta algun archivo!")
    x = messagebox.askquestion("Setup", "¿Crear Archivos?")
    if x == "yes":
        archivo = open("datos.csv", "a")
        config = open("config.ini", "a")
        archivo.close()
        config.close()
        archivo = open("datos.csv")
        config = open("config.ini")
        longitud = 0
        for z in archivo:
            longitud = longitud + len(z)
        archivo.close()
        if longitud==0:
            archivo = open("datos.csv", "a")
            archivo.write("ID,Nombre,Apellidos,Equipo de Trabajo,Puntos Avante\n")
            archivo.close()
        longitud = 0
        for z in config:
            longitud = longitud + len(z)
        if longitud == 0:
            config = open("config.ini", "a")
            config.write("[Software]\nusuario = Root\ncontraseña = password")
            config.close()
        Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        Config.read("config.ini")
        messagebox.showinfo("Setup", "Archivos Creados Exitosamente")
        encriptar("#19UmPV@" , "config.ini")
        encriptar("#19UmPV@", "datos.csv")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Cerrando Programa", "Se necesitan los archivos para avanzar")
        exit()



contraseña_entrar = StringVar()
pass_etiqueta = Label(ventana , text = "¡Introduce La Contraseña!", bg = fondo, fg = letras, font= ("Helvetica", 16)).place(x = 30, y = 10)
pass_entry = Entry(ventana, textvariable = contraseña_entrar).place(x = 60, y = 60)
pass_boton = Button(ventana, text= "Entrar!", command = lambda: entrar(contraseña_entrar)).place(x = 60, y = 90)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra si haces `print(str(final_pass)) ` y `print(str(x))` en la función `entrar(x)` justo antes del `if`?

Comment: probe con print(str(final_pass)) y es password, que si es la contraseña correcta, voy a probar con la variable x para ver que es lo que leyó del usuario. Te lo reporto en breve.

Comment: Ahi esta el error xD, por alguna razón x se iguala a PY_VAR0

Comment: He creado una respuesta sobre el porqué pasa.... Es curioso pero es la segunda vez hoy que veo el mismo error y en un principio pensé en algún problema de encoding. Yo ante estos casos lo lleno todo de `print()`, es un método brusco pero funciona para localizar donde está el problema :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) es un contenedor y debes usar el método [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) para leer el dato contenido en ella. Si se usa el nombre de la instancia lo que se retorna es el contenido del atributo 'para uso interno' `_name` y no el valor almacenado:

Por ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set('Hola Mundo')


print(var)
print(var._name)
print(root.globalgetvar('PY_VAR0'))
print(var.get())
```

Nos retorna:

```
PY_VAR0
PY_VAR0
Hola Mundo
Hola Mundo
```

Como podemos ver PY_VAR0 solo es el nombre interno por defecto que se le asigna a la instancia, no el valor que almacena. Esto lleva a confución realmente. De hecho se puede cambiar usando el parámetro `name` del constructor:

```
var = tk.StringVar(name = 'MiVariable')
```

El constructor completo es:

```
def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None)
```

**En definitiva, cambia:**

```
pass_boton = Button(ventana, text= "Entrar!", command = lambda: entrar(contraseña_entrar)).place(x = 60, y = 90)
```

por:

```
pass_boton = Button(ventana, text= "Entrar!", command = lambda: entrar(contraseña_entrar.get())).place(x = 60, y = 90)
```

Comment: Gracias a Todos